# Intermediate Aggregate function & Data manipulation in SQL

Tags: python, sql

I have a question that kindly need assistance in respect of aggregate function and Data manipulation in SQL.

My Code seemly can output the results by summarize the value when ID is equal to 10 and adding a new column "Updated ID".

```
SELECT SUM(Value), ID as 'Updated ID' FROM Test_DATABASE Where ID = xxx10xxx
```

One thing I want to achieve is the output will automatically summarize the values with all ID in the data, and then adding extra column "Update ID" by only output the 4th and 5th digits in the initial ID column.

Data

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| xxx10xxx | 5 |
| xxx10xxx | 6 |
| xxx11xxx | 7 |
| xxx12xxx | 8 |
| xxx12xxx | 9.5 |
| xxx13xxx | 10 |
| xxx13xxx | 0 |

My output

| ID | Value | Updated ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xxx10xxx | 11 | xxx10xxx |

Expectation Output

| ID | Value | Updated ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xxx10xxx | 11 | 10 |
| xxx11xxx | 7 | 11 |
| xxx12xxx | 17.5 | 12 |
| xxx13xxx | 10 | 13 |

Comment: What if you have xxx100xxx? 4th and 5th digits would get you 10 instead of 100

Comment: What engine do you use on you sql? Is it MS SQL Server?

Comment: Likely your DBMS is either MySQL or maybe SQLite that allows an aggregate query to run without error though it contains a non-aggregated `SELECT` column without `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:  Your query can't possibly produce that output.

1. `xxx10xxx` is a string, so it must be in quotes.
2. Your ID comes first in your output, but second in your query.
3. There are three columns in your output, but only two in your query.
4. You are using an aggregate function, but no `GROUP BY` clause.

So you didn't provide a minimal, reproducible problem.  So I will.  Here is what it looks like will produce your initial problem.

```sql
create table Test_DATABASE (
    ID varchar(8) not null,
    Value decimal(15,5) not null
)
;


insert into Test_DATABASE
VALUES  ('xxx10xxx', 5)
, ('xxx10xxx', 6)
, ('xxx11xxx', 7)
, ('xxx12xxx', 8)
, ('xxx12xxx', 9.5)
, ('xxx13xxx', 10)
, ('xxx13xxx', 0)
;



SELECT ID as "Updated ID"
, SUM(Value) as "Value"
, ID as "Updated ID"

FROM Test_DATABASE

Where ID = 'xxx10xxx'

group by ID
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=4dfb5322e3f7e78591015a8b89a3b3d0

I think you can do what you want by not having a `WHERE` clause and adding a `SUBSTRING`:

```sql
create table Test_DATABASE (
    ID varchar(8) not null,
    Value decimal(15,5) not null
)
;


insert into Test_DATABASE
VALUES  ('xxx10xxx', 5)
, ('xxx10xxx', 6)
, ('xxx11xxx', 7)
, ('xxx12xxx', 8)
, ('xxx12xxx', 9.5)
, ('xxx13xxx', 10)
, ('xxx13xxx', 0)
;



SELECT ID
, SUM(Value) as "Value"
, SUBSTRING(ID, 4, 2) as "Updated ID"

FROM Test_DATABASE

--Where ID = 'xxx10xxx'

group by ID

order by "Updated ID"
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=cda174ec2ed1bcfa7fbe8d4461a91ac7

You didn't specify the data types of the output, so you may need to make some adjustments.